# Animating Meshes in Open GL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, blender, caanimation

How do I animate an object in Open GL ES. I know you can import meshes from Blender, and I know how to animate them in Blender. Will the animations I make in Blender show up on the screen or do I need to use CAAnimation or something else? What would that something else be?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CAAnimation, it's for animating views. *Nothing* will "show up on the screen" with OpenGL ES -- you need to do everything from scratch.

You first need to find a way to get your animations out of Blender and into OpenGL ES. As far as I know the easiest way to do this is to export in the COLLADA file format. You will then need to find a preexisting exporter or write your own exporter to get the mesh, normal, animation transformation and timing data into a form that you can give to OpenGL, and write a shader (or several shaders, depending on how sophisticated these animations are) that can turn that input into an animation resembling what you had in Blender.

In lieu of the CAAnimation, you'll have either a CADisplaylink callback or a `DrawFrame` method on a GLKView which will be called every time the screen refreshes to draw your view. Depending on how your App's logic works, you might increment a float indicating what time you are in in a animation that you pass to your shader as a uniform to determine where to draw the object.

Once you have the Collada export working, you should create an intermediate format that makes sense for your program -- In my experience Collada can take a *long* time to parse.